# Implementation of Immutable class in Java

Tags: java, immutability

In my application, I need to make my class as immutable, but in my class I have an object of other class which is mutable, can anyone please suggest me Implementation.

Pseudo code:

Class `A` which I would like as immutable class

```
class A {
    /* ... */ 

    //class B is mutable
    B b = new B();
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Comment: Make b private inside the instance

Comment: ... and `final`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to access `b` from outside world, you will need to wrap all methods on B and declare those in `A`.
Additionally, take `b` as constructor parameter, without getter/setter method.

```
class A{
   private final b;
   A(B b){
     this.b = b;    
   }
   public String getSomeValue(){
     return b.getSomeValue();
   }

}
```

Edit: Refer to Hoopje' comment regarding cloning `b` in constructor. If `clone` or copy constructor not available on `B` then you have to construct new `B` on your own in `A`

Comment: You should make a copy of `b` in the constructor. Now, you can save a reference to the `B` object elsewhere and change the object after creating the `A` object, thus changing the immutable `A` object.

Comment: additionally, make your class final to prohibit inheritance